# Loading WordPress Posts on a html page

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, rest, reactjs

I am trying to load posts outside WordPress on a static html page. So far I have a working example using React, http://v2.wp-api.org/ and https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios. This working example using react currently displays the posts properly but it is fragile and there is no fall back. Codepen example here, https://codepen.io/krogsgard/pen/NRBqPp/

I use this example to get my feed source using axios `axios.get(this.props.source)`. Then I use the examples react function to grab my latest three posts, including titles and images and load them into a static html page via

```
 render: function render() {
    return React.createElement(
        "div",
        { className: "post-wrapper" },
        this.state.posts.map(function (post) {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                { key: post.link, className: "post" },
                React.createElement(
                    "h2",
                    { className: "post-title" },
                    React.createElement("a", {
                        href: post.link,
                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: post.title.rendered }
                    })
                ),
                post.featured_media ? React.createElement(
                    "a",
                    { href: post.link },
                    React.createElement("img", { src: post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url })
                ) : null
            );
        })
    );
}
```

My blog's source wp json is

```
React.render(React.createElement(App, { source: 
"myBlogURL.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?_embed&per_page=3" }), 
document.querySelector("#blog-post"));
```

Which correctly loads my latest 3 blog posts into the `<div id="blog-posts">`
I'm looking for a vanilla js way to do this with some fallback helpers. In case I forget to include the featured image to a post, the posts will not fail to load. Any ideas or examples would greatly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

*You are working way to hard for this. Wordpress CMS is designed for stuff like this. You are able to display posts in the form of a RSS feed by categories, tags and other [taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). pretty easily*

• If you are not too good with code, you can find many [widgets](http://www.vandelaydesign.com/display-your-feed-on-a-static-html-page-using-feedburners-buzzboost/) that'll take care of most of the work.

• If you need to do it yourself, below should get you there with JSON / jQuery.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var MYBLOG_LIMIT = 3;
var MYWRAPPER_CLASS = 'homeblog';

var WP={open:function(b){var a={posts:function(){var d=MYBLOG_LIMIT;var e=0;var c={all:function(g){var f=b+"/api/get_recent_posts/";f+="?count="+d+"&page="+e+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(f,function(l){var k=l.posts;for(var j=0;j<k.length;j++){var h=k[j];h.createComment=function(i,m){i.postId=h.id;a.comments().create(i,m)}}g(k)})},findBySlug:function(f,h){var g=b+"/api/get_post/";g+="?slug="+f+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(g,function(i){h(i.post)})},limit:function(f){d=f;return c},page:function(f){e=f;return c}};return c},pages:function(){var c={findBySlug:function(d,f){var e=b+"/api/get_page/";e+="?slug="+d+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(e,function(g){f(g.page)})}};return c},categories:function(){var c={all:function(e){var d=b+"/api/get_category_index/";d+="?callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(f){e(f.categories)})}};return c},tags:function(){var c={all:function(e){var d=b+"/api/get_tag_index/";d+="?callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(f){e(f.tags)})}};return c},comments:function(){var c={create:function(f,e){var d=b+"/api/submit_comment/";d+="?post_id="+f.postId+"&name="+f.name+"&email="+f.email+"&content="+f.content+"&callback=?";jQuery.getJSON(d,function(g){e(g)})}};return c}};return a}};

var blog = WP.open('https://www.fldtrace.com');
blog.posts().all(function(posts){
  for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++){
    jQuery('.'+MYWRAPPER_CLASS).append(function(){
      return (posts[i].thumbnail) ? '<a class="lastpost_title" href="'+posts[i].url+'">
<h4>'+posts[i].title+'</h4>

</a><a href="'+posts[i].url+'"><img src="'+posts[i].thumbnail+'"/></a>' : '<a href="'+posts[i].url+'">
<h4>'+posts[i].title+'</h4>

</a>';

    });
  }
});
</script>
```

---

```
<div class="homeblog">
</div>
```

---

> **You need to configure the next options**
>
> var MYBLOG_LIMIT = 1; will define how many posts will show. By default
>   is 1. var MYWRAPPER_CLASS = ‘homeblog’; – the class name of HTML
>   element where the post(s) will be shown. var blog =
>   WP.open(‘https://www.fldtrace.com/’); – this should link to your blog
>   main domain (mandatory) by default, will be shown the post thumbnail
>   and title both linked. The rest is CSS customization, including
>   adjusting the thumbnail size.

Read more [here](https://www.fldtrace.com/display-latest-post-outside-of-wordpress-with-json-and-jquery) at source article.